# Error importing SQL dump into MySQL: Unknown database / Can't create database

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1049, mysql-error-1007

I'm confused how to import a SQL dump file.  I can't seem to import the database without creating the database first in MySQL.

This is the error displayed when `database_name` has not yet been created:

`username` = username of someone with access to the database on the original server.
`database_name` = name of database from the original server

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h localhost database_name < dumpfile.sql   
Enter password:  
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'database_name'
```

If I log into MySQL as root and create the database, `database_name`

```
mysql -u root  
create database database_name;  
create user username;# same username as the user from the database I got the dump from.  
grant all privileges on database_name.* to username@"localhost" identified by 'password';  
exit mysql
```

then attempt to import the sql dump again:

```
$ mysql -u username -p database_name < dumpfile.sql  
Enter password:  
ERROR 1007 (HY000) at line 21: Can't create database 'database_name'; database exists
```

How am I supposed to import the SQL dumpfile?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Open the sql file and comment out the line that tries to create the existing database.

Comment: @BryanWheelock I think a better (industrializable) option would be not to select the database in your command, so it becomes: "mysql -u username -p -h localhost < dumpfile.sql". The database_name is an optional parameter. If your dump file contains a "create database" instruction, then it will be created.

Comment: Just to elaborate on this a bit, the very first line in my *.sql file had this on it: 

CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS \`database_name\` /\*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 \*/;

Changing this to (note /\* at start): 

/\*CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS \`database_name\` /\*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 \*/;

effectively comments out the command and IMPORT should work. 

Just remember to be active inside the database that you want the IMPORT to insert the tables into, otherwise you might be in for a mess!

Answer (score 54):

This is a **known bug** at MySQL.

[bug 42996](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42996)
[bug 40477](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40477)

As you can see this has been a known issue since 2008 and they have not fixed it yet!!!

**WORK AROUND**
You first need to create the database to import. It doesn't need any tables. Then you can import your database.

1. first start your MySQL command line (apply username and password if you need to)
   `C:\>mysql -u user -p`
2. Create your database and exit

   ```
   mysql> DROP DATABASE database;  
   mysql> CREATE DATABASE database;  
   mysql> Exit
   ```
3. Import your selected database from the dump file
   `C:\>mysql -u user -p -h localhost -D database -o < dumpfile.sql`

You can replace localhost with an IP or domain for any MySQL server you want to import to.
The reason for the DROP command in the mysql prompt is to be sure we start with an empty and clean database.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. It's now 2012 and it appears that the bug is still there, for I used your answer to get my wordpress databae restored to a new server (note however, your MySQL commends are missing the ending ';'. ;-)

Comment: 2022 and bug still around ;)

Comment: this is a real pain in the ass when writing phing targets. not everybody works just on the command line :/

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like your database dump includes the information for creating the database.  So don't give the MySQL command line a database name.  It will create the new database and switch to it to do the import.

Answer (score 4):

If you create your database in direct admin or cpanel, you must edit your sql with notepad or notepad++ and change `CREATE DATABASE` command to `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS` in line22

Answer (score 0):

I create the database myself using the command line. Then try to import again, it works.