# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I'm start my own study on php using wamp but when I try to establish a connection between my database and php code I always receive this message. 
I tried some diferent courses and for all of then I recieve this error. 
I tried to reinstall wamp server, verify some privilegies, the phpmyadmin create tables, insert into database normally but the code doesn't connect to the database.

Below is my connection code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost"; //default by wamp, I don't change the port, still using 80.
    $database = 'curso_estoque'; //created on phpmyadmin
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $conexao = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
 ?>
```

Comment: You must be giving an incorrect database name in the arguments to `mysqli_connect()`. Check the name carefully.

Comment: Where your code?

Comment: I checked the name, but this error happened in other tutorial that I tried, first of all I thoght that was something that I forgot or misstep but when I change the tutorial I kept receving the same error;
The code above is the one who I'm using, my database is "curso_estoque" (created on phpmyadmin on mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created a database and you are in the same one, query 
like

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabasename;
USE mydatabasename;
```

Refer :- [ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mydatabasename'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678769/error-1049-42000-unknown-database-mydatabasename)

Comment: "Unknown database" comes from the server, it must already be running.

Comment: You're missing the database argument to `new mysqli()`.

Comment: I typed the command USE with my databasename but doesn't work;
Yes, the server is running, I can use normally mysql commands on phpmyadmin;
I serchead on php documentation and tried use the argument new mysqli() but the error still the same.