# Mariadb use database command giving 1049 error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, mariadb-10.3, mariasql

Getting 1049 sqlstate 42000 error when trying to do

Use  command

The database is being shown in show databases command

Comment: Please show the "show databases" output and error message returned by  "use <dbname>"

Comment: see this thread may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678769/error-1049-42000-unknown-database-mydatabasename

Comment: What OS?  Is there a capitalization difference?